# awk keep if line contains " example "

Tags: awk, cygwin, gawk, gnuwin32

okay so I wish to keep lines containing several keywords,

example of list:

```
Name:email:username #registered
Name2:email2:username2
Name3:email3:username3 #registered #subscribed #phonever
Name4:email4:username4 #unconfirmed
```

What I want to do is extract lines if they contain " #registered, #subscribed, #phonever

example of output I want,

```
Name:email:username #registered
Name3:email3:username3 #registered #subscribed #phonever
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `awk` (use regex alternation operator, `|`, on a list of fixed strings):

```
awk '/#registered|#subscribed|#phonever/' file
```

The part under `/.../` is called an [`awk` pattern](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Pattern-Overview) and for the matching lines it executes the action that follows (as `{ ... }`). But since the default action is: `{ print $0 }` (printing the complete input record/line), there's no need to specify it here.

Similarly with `sed` you could say:

```
sed -nE '/#registered|#subscribed|#phonever/p' file
```

but now we have to specify `-n` to skip printing by default, and print with the `p` command only those lines that match the pattern (called `sed` address). The `-E` tells `sed` to used POSIX ERE (extended regex), and we need it here, because the default, POSIX BRE (basic regex) does not define the alternation operator.

For simple filtering (and printing the lines that match some pattern), `grep` is also an option (and a very fast option at that):

```
grep '#registered\|#subscribed\|#phonever' file
```

---

#### A bit more general solution (`awk` with patterns file)

Solution for larger (and possibly dynamic) lists of patterns could be to keep all patterns in a separate file, for example in `patterns`:

```
#registered
#subscribed
#phonever
```

and to use this `awk` program:

```
awk 'NR==FNR { pat[$0]=1 } NR>FNR { for (p in pat) if ($0 ~ p) {print;next} }' patterns file
```

which will first load all patterns into `pat` array, and then try to match any of those patterns on each of the lines in `file`, printing and advancing on to the next line on the first match found.

The result is the same:

```
Name:email:username #registered
Name3:email3:username3 #registered #subscribed #phonever
```

but the script now doesn't change for each new set of patterns. Note however, this caries a performance penalty (as general solutions usually do). For shorter lists of patterns and smaller files, this shouldn't be a problem.

---

#### And a lot faster variant of the above (`grep` with fixed-string patterns file)

Building on the approach from above (of keeping a list of fixed-string "patterns" in a file), we can actually use `grep` -- which provides a specialized option (`-f FILE`) for obtaining patterns from file, one per line.  To further speed-up the matching, we should also use `-F`/`--fixed-strings` option.

So, this:

```
grep -Ff patterns file
```

will be incredibly fast, handling long lists of fixed-string patterns and huge files with minimal memory overhead.

Comment: this works thank you :), but if the list is large it doesn't work, I have to reduce to 3 keywords rather than 10 or 20 etc, not sure if that's because i copy and pasted rather than typed

Comment: It should work for larger lists too. But if your list of patterns is in a file, the `awk` script can be modified to handle that, without the need to retype it. If you want I can add it to my answer.

Comment: Added a solution for dynamic lists of patterns.

Comment: Thank you Randomir pat works great :), really appreciate your help.

Comment: Alteratively: `awk 'NR==FNR { re=(NR>1?re "|":"") $0; next } $0~re' regexps file`. I hate the word `pattern` as it's so ambiguous - we should just use "string" or "regexp" (or "globbing pattern"), whichever we mean.

Comment: @EdMorton, nice, I didn't think of that. What do you think would be faster for a large list of keywords (not regexps)?

Comment: I'd think the `|`-separated regexp. It might actually be fastest to split the `#`-strings and do a hash lookup (`in`) on each line. I'll post a solution based on that and anyone who likes can try it.

Comment: @randomir I added a solution at https://stackoverflow.com/a/45538112/1745001 that involves generating all possible combinations of the key words first and then just doing a hash lookup of each line of the input file to see if any of those combinations are present. Enjoy :-).

Comment: @EdMorton, as much as your solution is interesting, I think, in this use case, we can't beat `grep` (see my edit) with `awk`. :)

Comment: The grep approach will fail when one of the target values appears elsewhere on the line or can appear as part of a different value e.g. if a "username" contains #phonenum or #foo is a target string and #foobar can also be present.

Comment: @EdMorton, that's true; each solution has some assumptions. (Like your solution will fail if any of the fields contains a space.)

Answer (score 0):

Simple ***awk*** approach:

```
awk '/#(registered|subscribed|phonever)/' file
```

The output:

```
Name:email:username #registered
Name3:email3:username3 #registered #subscribed #phonever
```

---

- `(registered|subscribed|phonever)` - regexp alternation group to match a single regular expression out of several possible regular expressions

Comment: I thought the practice on SO was to refrain from posting identical answers. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR==FNR {
    strings[$0]
    next
}
{
    for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) {
        if ($i in strings) {
            print
            next
        }
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk strings file
Name:email:username #registered
Name3:email3:username3 #registered #subscribed #phonever

$ cat strings
#registered
#subscribed
#phonever

$ cat file
Name:email:username #registered
Name2:email2:username2
Name3:email3:username3 #registered #subscribed #phonever
Name4:email4:username4 #unconfirmed
```

If your file was huge and your set of target words relatively small and speed of execution was important to you then you could do this to generate every possible combination of every possible non-empty subset of those target words:

```
$ cat subsets.awk
###################
# Calculate all subsets of a given set, see
# https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set

function get_subset(A,subsetNr,numVals, str, sep) {
    while (subsetNr) {
        if (subsetNr%2 != 0) {
            str = str sep A[numVals]
            sep = " "
        }
        numVals--
        subsetNr = int(subsetNr/2)
    }
    return str
}

function get_subsets(A,B,       i,lgth) {
    lgth = length(A)
    for (i=1;i<2^lgth;i++) {
        B[get_subset(A,i,lgth)]
    }
}

###################

# Input should be a list of strings
{
    split($0,A)
    delete B
    get_subsets(A,B)
    for (subset in B) {
        print subset
    }
}
```

.

```
$ cat permutations.awk
###################
# Calculate all permutations of a set of strings, see
# https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap%27s_algorithm

function get_perm(A,            i, lgth, sep, str) {
    lgth = length(A)
    for (i=1; i<=lgth; i++) {
        str = str sep A[i]
        sep = " "
    }
    return str
}

function swap(A, x, y,  tmp) {
    tmp  = A[x]
    A[x] = A[y]
    A[y] = tmp
}

function generate(n, A, B,      i) {
    if (n == 1) {
        B[get_perm(A)]
    }
    else {
        for (i=1; i <= n; i++) {
            generate(n - 1, A, B)
            if ((n%2) == 0) {
                swap(A, 1, n)
            }
            else {
                swap(A, i, n)
            }
        }
    }
}

function get_perms(A,B) {
    generate(length(A), A, B)
}

###################

# Input should be a list of strings
{
    split($0,A)
    delete B
    get_perms(A,B)
    for (perm in B) {
        print perm
    }
}
```

.

```
$ echo '#registered #subscribed #phonever' |
    awk -f subsets.awk |
    awk -f permutations.awk
#registered #subscribed #phonever
#subscribed #phonever #registered
#phonever #subscribed #registered
#phonever #registered #subscribed
#subscribed #registered #phonever
#registered #phonever #subscribed
#phonever
#subscribed
#registered #subscribed
#subscribed #registered
#registered
#registered #phonever
#phonever #registered
#subscribed #phonever
#phonever #subscribed
```

and then you could make the rest of the processing just a simple hash lookup:

```
$ echo '#registered #subscribed #phonever' |
    awk -f subsets.awk |
    awk -f permutations.awk |
    awk 'NR==FNR{strings[$0];next} {k=(NF>1?$0:"");sub(/[^ ]+ /,"",k)} k in strings' - file
Name:email:username #registered
Name3:email3:username3 #registered #subscribed #phonever
```

Comment: It's a cute prototype, but totally unpractical for more than 5-6 strings/patterns. With a factorial explosion around 8-9 strings -- for 10 strings it generates `~10M` combinations with `>600MB` memory overhead. And that's only the generation part. :)

Comment: For 10 strings it took 2 mins to generate the set of 9,864,100 combinations. Might still be faster than looping through the strings for every line of the input file depending on the size of the input file. As I mentioned it's for the case where the input file is large and set of strings small.

Comment: You did mention it, I just wanted to emphasize the magnitude of "small" we're talking about.