# Use awk to remove lines with strings stored in list

Tags: bash, unix, awk

Trying to figure out how to store a list as a variable (array?) and use it in with awk.

I have a file like such:

```
Jimmy
May31
John
June19
Paul
Aug15
Mark
Sept1
David
Nov15
```

I want to use awk to search my file and remove three names and the line following each of those names. So the final file should only contain 2 names (and birthdays).

I can do this with:

```
awk '/Jimmy|Mark|David/{n=2}; n {n--; next}; 1' < file
```

But is there a way to store the "Jimmy|Mark|David" list in the above command as a variable/array and do the same thing. (The real project I've working on has a much longer list to match in a much bigger file).

Thanks!

Comment: You can pass variables into awk using `-v`, if that will achieve your goal. See [The GNU Awk User's Guide](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gawk/gawk_165.html) for some info on how that and other very useful Awk flags work

Comment: I haven't been able to figure out the -v and ~ syntax except for a very simple example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the list in a variable like this:

`LIST=$(cat list.txt | tr "\n" "|")`

and then use @randomir 's answer

`awk -v pat=$LIST '$0~pat {n=2}; n {n--; next}; 1' birthdays`

if I put your list:

```
Jimmy
John
Paul
Mark
David
```

into the file list.txt

`LIST=$(cat list.txt | tr "\n" "|")`

will output

`Jimmy|John|Paul|Mark|David`

providing you don't add a linebreak at the end of the last line

Comment: MrE can you spell out the full list? I am not reading it from a file and I can't seem to adapt your example

Comment: list.txt is the list you provided

Comment: the list I provided is the file to be searched for matches "Jimmy, Mark and David"...so the variable is Jimmy, mark, david

Comment: but it seems to me, the way you are looking at this, you want to just remove one \n every other line, and then you'll have `Name Birthday` on the same line. Then use awk to read whatever you want for each line.

Comment: Thanks. If I modify the list to include only the three names, it does what I want it to

Comment: @user2414840, if you have a list of names in a file, have a look at my (updated) answer for an alternative (faster/simpler) solution. It uses only `grep`, and it should be faster than `awk`, particularly for long lists of names.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with the [`-v`/`--assign` option](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#index-_002dv-option):

```
awk -v pat='Jimmy|Mark|David' '$0~pat {n=2}; n {n--; next}; 1' birthdays
```

and then invoke regex comparison manually with `~` operator on the complete line.

Alternatively, if you have a long list of names to filter out in a file, `grep` with `-f` would probably be much faster option (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45536254/404556)). For example:

```
$ cat names
Jimmy
Mark
David

$ paste - - <birthdays | grep -vFf names | tr '\t' '\n'
John
June19
Paul
Aug15
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it would be easier to do this:

Patch 2 lines together
`cat file | paste - -`

then use awk to do what you need to do

```
$ cat list.txt| paste - -                                                                                                                                                                          
Jimmy   May31
John    June19
Paul    Aug15
Mark    Sept1
David   Nov15
```

Comment: you can do the same in awk by the way, but it's more obscure:
`awk 'ORS=NR%2?" ":"\n"' `